# Removing assembly information from logger name in log4net

Tags: log4net

I am working on my log4net logging system, and I'm having trouble figuring out a way to get rid of assembly information in the %logger entry. The logging pattern looks like this `conversionPattern value="[%60logger]] %message%newline"`, but when the line is printed out in the log, the logger is showing assembly information such as `Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]`. I believe that this is being caused by the fact that the logger is being created from a generic type, but I'm not sure. I need to get rid of that assembly information, but I don't want to changed every instance of `GetLogger`.

Answer (score 3):

%logger should printout the name of the logger, only if that name contains the `Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` than that is also printed. Check what you do when you get your loggers:

```
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program).FullName); //Gives name + Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

If you want the type name, do something like:

```
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program); //Gives name only
```

Test program to see the names returned:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(GenericClass<Program>));
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(GenericClass<Program>).Name);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(GenericClass<Program>).FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(GenericClass<Program>).ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class GenericClass<T> { }
}
```

Output:

```
ConsoleApp2.Program+GenericClass`1[ConsoleApp2.Program]
GenericClass`1
ConsoleApp2.Program+GenericClass`1[[ConsoleApp2.Program, ConsoleApp2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
ConsoleApp2.Program+GenericClass`1[ConsoleApp2.Program]
```